# Does the air cushion on which the original hyperloop will sit require energy constantly or not

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Does the air cushion on which the original hyperloop idea envisioned by Elon Musk  require energy constantly to keep afloat, as the hovercraft does or would it be designed as the modern air suspension where energy requirement is once off, air is let into the  suspension cylinder, vehicle is floating in air then valves and seals take over.